# 405 status when hitting actions for GET in controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

The idea is that with these **ItemController** methods I should be able to:

- Get the items by barcode when hitting "item/query?barcode={barcode}"
- Get the items by discount when hitting "item/query?discount={discount}"
- Get the items by name when hitting "item/query?name={name}"
- Get the items by category when hitting "item/query?category={category}"

And this is my code for actions under the GET verb:

```c#
[HttpGet("query/{barcode:int}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetByBarcode(int barcode)
{
    var item = ...
    
    return Ok(item);
}

[HttpGet("query/{discount:int}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetByDiscount(int discount)
{
    var items =  ...
    
    return Ok(items);
}


[HttpGet("query/{name}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetByName(string name)
{
    var items = ...
    
    return Ok(items);
}

[HttpGet("query/{category}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetByCategory(string category)
{
    var items = ...
    
    return Ok(items);
}
```

The problem is that I keep getting **405 Method Not Allowed** when I try to access to any of those actions. I don't know if it's a matter of ambiguity between the methods, can you help me out?

**Edit:**

Header of ItemController.cs:

```c#
using InventoryWebApi.DataAccess;
using InventoryWebApi.DTO;
using InventoryWebApi.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace InventoryWebApi.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class ItemController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly IRepository repository;

        public ItemController(IRepository repository)
...
```

Comment: Can you show your controller header too? and maybe startup endpoints will be usefull too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are using routing a wrong way.

Your code will not be even run,
your actions shoud be

```
[HttpGet("query/getbybarcode/{barcode:int})]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetByBarcode(int barcode)

[HttpGet("query/getbydiscount/{discount:int}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetByDiscount(int discount)
```

For this routes you have to use this urls

```
.../item/query/getbybarcode/{barcode}
..../item/query/getbydiscount/{discount}
```

if you still want to create url your way you will have to change attribute routing

```
[HttpGet("query/getbybarcode)]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetByBarcode(int barcode)

[HttpGet("query/getbydiscount")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetByDiscount(int discount)
```

and your url should be

```
.../item/query/getbydiscount?discount={discount}"
..../item/query/getbybarcode?barcode={barcode}"
```

Update

If you still need to use all your urls for your student project , then the only way is to use one action for all your urls

```
[HttpGet("query")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Get(int? barcode, int? discount, 
string name, string category )
{
 
   if (barcode != null) ...
else if (discount!=null) ...


    var item = ...
    
    return Ok(item);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I understand it, but then definitely there's no other way to achieve what is proposed in the description, isn't there?   Bc it's an exercise from Hackerrank and it explicitly says that the parameter should be after "/query?" in the route for every case, without the name of the action or anything else

Comment: @LuisBarreto Check my update